# react native router flux Encountered two children with the same key

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, react-native, router, flux

### Version(s)

- react-native-router-flux v3.31.2
- react-native v15.2.1

I don't know what i'm doing wrong but when i try to call `Actions.dialog()` multiple times, i got this error.

I thought this fix https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/327 fixed it but it isn't, it should be something else then but i'm out of ideas ...

The only time i dont have this, is when i use pop() to close it. Unfortunalty, i dont want to pop (it may break other functionalities in my app).

Could someone help ?

#### The error :

```
`1:$dialog_1_dialog`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Modal)
    in Modal (created by DefaultRenderer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DefaultRenderer)
    in DefaultRenderer (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NavigationCard)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent (created by NavigationCard)
    in NavigationCard (created by Container)
    in Container (created by NavigationComponent)
    in NavigationComponent (created by NavigationAnimatedView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by NavigationAnimatedView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by NavigationAnimatedView)
    in NavigationAnimatedView (created by NavigationComponent)
    in NavigationComponent (created by DefaultRenderer)
    in DefaultRenderer (created by NavigationRootContainer)
    in NavigationRootContainer (created by Router)
    in Router (created by Connect(Router))
    in Connect(Router) (created by CdiscountReact)
    in Provider (created by CdiscountReact)
    in CdiscountReact
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
2016-08-08 14:23:04.269 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `1:$dialog_2_dialog`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Modal)
    in Modal (created by DefaultRenderer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DefaultRenderer)
    in DefaultRenderer (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NavigationCard)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent (created by NavigationCard)
    in NavigationCard (created by Container)
    in Container (created by NavigationComponent)
    in NavigationComponent (created by NavigationAnimatedView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by NavigationAnimatedView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by NavigationAnimatedView)
    in NavigationAnimatedView (created by NavigationComponent)
    in NavigationComponent (created by DefaultRenderer)
    in DefaultRenderer (created by NavigationRootContainer)
    in NavigationRootContainer (created by Router)
    in Router (created by Connect(Router))
    in Connect(Router) (created by CdiscountReact)
    in Provider (created by CdiscountReact)
    in CdiscountReact
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

#### The code

```
<Scene key="modal" component={Modal} >
  <Scene key="root">
    <Scene key="launch" initial={true} component={Launch} />
    ...
  </Scene>

  {/*Modals*/}
  ...
  <Modal key="dialog" component={Dialog} direction="vertical"/>
</Scene>
```

Comment: I finaly found out a hack / solution : https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1035#issuecomment-238877606

Answer (score 0):

Hope can help:

```
<Modal key="dialog" clone component={Dialog} direction="vertical"/>
```